# MySql Update a column based on table join - Error 1093

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-error-1093

```
UPDATE AMAZON 
SET AMARBELEG =  (
                   Select Rechnungen.Rechnungsnummer 
                   from Rechnungen,Amazon 
                   where Rechnungen.Belegtext = Amazon.orderid
                 );
```

Hello i am trying to prevent the

> error code 1093.

I have tried several workarounds, but seem not to quite understand the idea of the tmptable.
Could anybody explain with my Tables, how i can prevent the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
UPDATE AMAZON A
JOIN Rechnungen R ON R.Belegtext = A.orderid
SET A.AMARBELEG = R.Rechnungsnummer;
```

Comment: Thanks that worked like a treat, could not see the tree within the forest anymore.

Comment: @Locust Since the solution in this answer is the same as in the question I flagged as duplicate consider accepting the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
UPDATE AMAZON 
   SET AMARBELEG = (SELECT Rechnungen.Rechnungsnummer 
                      FROM Rechnungen 
                     WHERE Rechnungen.Belegtext = Amazon.orderid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to prevent mysql 1093 error.

```
UPDATE AMAZON 
SET AMARBELEG =  ( SELECT r2.rechnr FROM 
                              ( Select Rechnungen.Rechnungsnummer 
                                   from Rechnungen,Amazon 
                                 where Rechnungen.Belegtext = Amazon.orderid
                               ) r2
                 );
```